# Problema com CORS

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-rs

Estou fazendo uma requisição através do AngularJS na porta 3000:

```
function _registrarNovaAposta(aposta) {return $http.post("http://localhost:8080/sga-api/apostas/nova-aposta", aposta);}
```

para o endpoint:

```
@POST
@Path("/nova-aposta")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String registrarNovaAposta(Aposta aposta) {
    apostaService.registrar(aposta);
    return "ok";
}
```

mas recebo o seguinte erro no console: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/sga-api/apostas/nova-aposta' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

o problema é que o GET retorna os dados normalmente, mas com o POST da esse problema de CORS, já tentei configurar os "headers" no $http.post mas não funcionou.

Estou utilizando o servidor tomcat 9 no back-end

Answer (score 1):

Você pode configurar filtros pra política de cors no web.xml do tomcat

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

existem algumas configurações avançadas na [documentação](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter).

Ou você pode configurar os filtros de cors direto no java como nesse [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450494/how-to-enable-cross-domain-requests-on-jax-rs-web-services#answer-23631475)

```
package com.yourdomain.package;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter 
{

   @Override
   public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,finalContainerResponseContext cres) throws IOException 
    {
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
   }

}
```